# JScript Syntax Highlighter not working, any ideas?

Tags: javascript, php, html, syntaxhighlighter

Hello I am hoping someone can help I am trying to use [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) on a web page of mine. I have followed the installation instructions by extracting the following files:

shCore.css
shThemeDefault.css
shCore.js
shBrushPowerShell.js

Basically all I can see is the code from the script file but it isn't highlighted. Here is my code on script.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="../stylesheets/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../stylesheets/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/shBrushPowerShell.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     SyntaxHighlighter.all()
</script>

<pre class="brush: ps">
<?php
    $filename = $_GET['file'];
    $filecontent = file_get_contents($filename);
    echo $filecontent;
?>
</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone see what the problem is here? I am a bit stuck, have I missed something fundamental? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS - all links to CSS and JS files are working as tested clicking them in "View Source" in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to put the following just before the closing body tag `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     SyntaxHighlighter.all()
</script>
```

And the following code in the `head`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/shBrushPowerShell.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Amir, thanks for replying. Indeed, this is how I had it to begin with, it makes no difference still the same result. Can see the code to be highlighted but it isn't highlighted.

Comment: Hi Amir, thanks, I have never used jsfiddle here's my attempt. http://jsfiddle.net/29rgp/ - PS adding the script tags to the header also made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

I had only uploaded the files mentioned above. I uploaded the whole of the zip file and used absolute URL's in the  and  tabs and it started working. Thanks to Amir for trying to help.